# How to use .Net WebClient to UploadString using Firebase AccessToken

Tags: c#, json, rest, firebase

Using C#, .Net 4.5 in a Windows Service application, REST formatted JSON objects wanting to upload to and to query the database.

I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax for the URI needed to connect to Firebase for using `WebClient.UploadString()`, I've used the code below successfully before with uploads to a GAS database. But we're now migrating to Firebase. I've managed to dynamically get an Access Token using the OAuth2 API, and presumably I need to include that in the URI I use in the method call. Does anyone have a small snip(S) of code with literal strings so that I can see the correct syntax? I suspect also that Headers may require different values?

```
WebClient webClnt = new WebClient();
webClnt.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
string result = 
   webClnt
      .UploadString(
          new Uri("https://myfirebaseDB123.firebaseio.com/????"),
          JSONObjectStr);
```

cheers,

Andy

Comment: Have you tried setting `Content-Type` to `application/json` or `text/plain`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Google support for pointing out the slight variation in syntax that allows the C# interaction with Firebase to succeed:

```
var connectionString = FirebaseServerURL + ".json?access_token=" + accessToken;
var webClnt = new WebClient();
result = webClnt.UploadString(connectionString, "PATCH", data);
```

So use "access_token=" rather than "auth=" in your URI and your in business. No additional 'web headers' required to be set in webClnt.

Note when "Auth" was used http 400 (bad request) was returned rather than 401 (un-authorised). Whereas 401 is returned if there is no attempt at authentication.

Comment: Why don't you just use an existing library? Such as https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet and https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet